# ethernet disconnected, shows up in ifconfig

Tags: 11.04, internet, networking, ifconfig

I am running 11.04, no remix. After installation, I could use wireless networks, but not ethernet. When I click on the connections menu item, it says

```
Wired Network
disconnected
```

How do I fix this?

Here is the ethernet portion of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:36:86:f3:43  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:17
```

And the result of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5788 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 03)
02:09.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
02:09.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments PCIxx12 OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller
02:09.4 Communication controller: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 GemCore based SmartCard controller
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Net
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

And I get no output from `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`.

Output from `nm-applet`:

```
** (nm-applet:1824): DEBUG: old state indicates that this was not a disconnect 0
** (nm-applet:1824): DEBUG: old state indicates that this was not a disconnect 0
```

On second run of `nm-applet`:

```
** (nm-applet:2752): DEBUG: old state indicates that this was not a disconnect 0
** (nm-applet:2752): DEBUG: old state indicates that this was not a disconnect 0

** (nm-applet:2752): WARNING **: _nm_object_get_property: Error getting 'WpaFlags' for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/10: (19) Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist



** (nm-applet:2752): WARNING **: _nm_object_get_property: Error getting 'RsnFlags' for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/10: (19) Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist



** (nm-applet:2752): WARNING **: Error in getting active connection 'Vpn' property: (19) Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist


** (nm-applet:2752): WARNING **: _nm_object_array_demarshal: couldn't create object for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
** Message: <info>  No keyring secrets found for Auto HeyJude88/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.


** (nm-applet:2752): WARNING **: applet.c.2882 (applet_settings_new_secrets_requested_cb): couldn't find details for connection
** Message: <info>  No keyring secrets found for Auto HeyJude88/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.

** (nm-applet:2752): DEBUG: going for offline with icon: notification-network-wireless-disconnected
** (nm-applet:2752): DEBUG: foo_client_state_changed_cb
** (nm-applet:2752): DEBUG: foo_client_state_changed_cb
** (nm-applet:2752): DEBUG: foo_client_state_changed_cb
** (nm-applet:2752): DEBUG: going for offline with icon: notification-network-wireless-disconnected
** (nm-applet:2752): DEBUG: foo_client_state_changed_cb
```

Here's more to `ifconfig`:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:de:31:70:20  
          inet addr:172.16.6.210  Bcast:172.16.6.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::218:deff:fe31:7020/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2384 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1367 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:514654 (514.6 KB)  TX bytes:215138 (215.1 KB)
```

Comment: Can you run this command `killall -9 nm-applet` followed by `nohup nm-applet &` this should create a file called nohup.out in your home folder can you add the contents if any to your question

Comment: Is nm network manager? What will this be doing?

Comment: see my edit for details

Comment: the commands will stop and restart network manager applet when you do this it will search for available connections and output messages to the nohup.out file.

Comment: Just posted the output. That's all there is. `1824` is the pid.

Comment: ran it a second time, more output

Comment: for the record, in my case, the `eth0` entry in the `/etc/network/interfaces` appears because I had installed `ubuntu-server` on my machine and then installed `ubuntu-desktop` and thus the network manager can't "see" the interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the interfaces file to remove

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Save and restart. Use Network manager to edit the connection and set it to automatically connect.

This command will open the interfaces file in Gedit with permission to save the file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

I have both a wired and a wireless connection and all that is in my interfaces file is these two lines

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I have found from experience than anything else will prevent a connection and removing what is extra will solve the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the original poster, but this didn't solve my problem.  My interfaces file matches yours.  The problem happens whenever I shutdown while connected to a wired network, then start back up without being connected to any network.  I can't connect to WiFi hot-spots.

Answer (score 1):

1. Basic layer 1 ground check - is your ethernet port connected and are you sure the wire and modem port are fine? Please confirm that the ethernet port light blinks (either green or amber) when you connect the wire. Otherwise it is a physical layer issue. Does it work on other machines at the same swtich-port?
2. Assuming the above is taken care of, Have you tried `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`?
3. Also, check your `/etc/network/interfaces` file and see if the following line is there

   auto eth0

   This automatically enables eth0 on startup

Comment: see my edit for details

Comment: Right click on the network manager icon and see if "Enable networking" icon is enabled

Comment: Enabled... Wireless works.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the same first command I mentioned in my comment

```
killall -9 nm-applet
```

Then

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

which will stop the network manager service
then enter this command

```
sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

Which will remove the NetworkManager.state file don't worry this file will be regenerated
the restart the network manager service with this command

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

and finally restart nm-applet with this command

```
nohup nm-applet &
```

It should hopefull be able to connect now.

The reason this happens is that the last time the network was disconected was because of a crash. Because the crash may be related to the network connection it is temporarily disabled to allow you to boot back in and fix the problem before re-enabling the connection.

Comment: I still get `Wired Networks \n disconnected` in the menu tray

Comment: added some more output from `ifconfig`, hope it's useful

Comment: This works for me, but the problem reappears whenever I shutdown while connected to a wireless network, then start back up without being connected to a network.  I'm not able to connect to any Wi-Fi hot-spots until I perform these steps.